# send data from one activity to another from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to retrieve all the records from table and show it in another activity,but when I do I am getting one record at a time and in reverse order.

I want all the records in single activity

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewAllActivity.class);//

        while (c.moveToNext()) {    
            i.putExtra("rollno", c.getString(0));
            i.putExtra("name", c.getString(1));
            i.putExtra("marks", c.getString(2));
            startActivity(i);
        }    
    }
});
```

**ViewAllActivity**

```
    String rollno=getIntent().getStringExtra("rollno");
    String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String marks=getIntent().getStringExtra("marks");
    TextView text;

    text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    String str="Roll no:"+rollno+"\nName:"+name+"\nmarks:"+marks;
    text.setText(str);
```

Comment: You starting new `Activity` every time the record is read?

Comment: how can i replace the code

Comment: Why don't you retrieve these datas in the `ViewAllActivity`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'l prefer just start your activity in the button click, and retrieve the data in the second activity.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewAllActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

ViewAllActivity

```
   //retrieve data to your cursor
    String str = "";
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        str = str + "Roll no:" + rollno + "\nName:" + name + "\nmarks:" + marks;
        text.setText(str);
    }
```

Comment: what if the OP needs the data in both activities ? better to pass the data to second activity that making two database communication

Comment: @robodev At the first line of the question OP wants to retrieve all the records from table and show it in **another activity**.

Comment: If you want to pass from one activity to another check @robo dev's answer. But in your case its unneccessary

Comment: i feel creating model will be not necessary, just fetch data and then send to another activity

Comment: But thats the proper way of programming

Comment: @PoojaNM You may not need that, but you have to follow this way. you should follow MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a model for doing the same..

example :

```
ArrayList<myModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

       while(c.moveToNext()){
         MyModel myModel = new MyModel();

         myModel.setRollNumber(c.getString(0));
         myModel.setName(c.getString(1));
         myModel.setMark(c.getString(2));
         modelList.add(myModel);

                    }
                }
            });

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(TAG, modelList);
startActivity(intent);
```

**MyModel**

```
public class MyModel implements Parcelable{

private String rollNumber;
private String name;
private String mark;

public void setRollNumner(String rollNumber){
this.rollNumber = rillNumber;
}
.....

}
```

the model should implement Parcelable  or Serializable

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i just start new intent activity and in some method in the second activity, oncreate or onstart retrieve your data from db.

But if you want to send your data in a bundle to the another one, you have to consider something

1.- you have to create a lis of your objets to send.

2.- to send arraylist or objects with a bundle you have to implement and extend Parcelable interface, otherwise will fail.

3.- if you use to send data vía bundle, is not good idea, could weak your performance, just think if your list are many objects, and you want to send vis bundle, app will bd slow. So think about.

Regards.